# Only user-defined types defined in public object modules can be coerced to or from a variant or passed to late-bound functions

Tags: vba, excel, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a structure that I can use to separate individual elements of a record in order to use their components. Each record consists of a record number, group, division, category, and 5 integer codes that will be used for various operations depending on their group, division, and categories. Whenever I try to pass a RecordType into my ArrayList I get the error as stated in the title of this question. I have tried looking at other questions that have this error, but none of the answers seemed to work. I have tried creating a separate class for the RecordType, but it says it cant be done with a public class type. Here is the data I am trying to separate and use:

```
65f8|gh|l1|9k|985|8437|7894|9495|3730|
4287|gh|w1|uk|7341|5638|7715|8906|698|
3s89|jk|w1|h7|225|487|2013|4328|4066|
62l5|lo|r5|9k|5103|9879|3448|2921|7581|
486p|lo|r5|uk|6882|9879|2672|1015|3160|
a597|lo|r6|m9|385|6915|3615|9195|9817|
1m36|hu|k8|h7|656|8064|3852|9110|9858|
```

And this is the code I have written. The comments are loops I have used to test certain parts of the code in excel.

```
Type RecordType
    number As String
    group As String
    div As String
    cat As String
    code1 As Integer
    code2 As Integer
    code3 As Integer
    code4 As Integer
    code5 As Integer
End Type

Sub ProgramOne()


Dim fileName As String, textData As String, fileLine As String, rowList() As String, numOfRecords As Integer, someString As String
Dim rowNum As Integer, colNum As Integer, counter As Integer, counter2 As Integer, groupCount As Integer, divCount As Integer, catCount As Integer
Dim groupBool As Boolean, catBool As Boolean, divBool As Boolean, groupList As Object, divList As Object, catList As Object

Set groupList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set divList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set catList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

fileName = "/Users/Ricky/Desktop/project1Data.txt"
Open fileName For Input As #1
rowNum = 1

Dim records As Object
Set records = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Dim placeholder As RecordType

Do Until EOF(1)
    numOfRecords = numOfRecords + 1
    Line Input #1, fileLine
    rowList = Split(fileLine, "|")

    placeholder.number = rowList(0)
    placeholder.group = rowList(1)
    placeholder.div = rowList(2)
    placeholder.cat = rowList(3)
    placeholder.code1 = rowList(4)
    placeholder.code2 = rowList(5)
    placeholder.code3 = rowList(6)
    placeholder.code4 = rowList(7)
    placeholder.code5 = rowList(8)

    records.Add (placeholder)
Loop

'Dim counter2 As Integer
'counter2 = 2
'    For x = 0 To UBound(records) - LBound(records)
'        Cells(counter2, 1) = records(x).group
'        Cells(counter2, 2) = records(x).div
'        counter2 = counter2 + 1
'    Next

Close #1

'For x = 0 To UBound(records) - LBound(records)

    divBool = False
    catBool = False

groupCount = 0
divCount = 0
catCount = 0
'Dim GroupName As Variant

'For Each GroupName In groupList
'    groupBool = False
'    For num = 0 To UBound(records) - LBound(records)
'        If CStr(records(num).group) = CStr(GroupName) Then
'            groupBool = True
'        End If
'        If Not groupBool Then
'            groupCount = groupCount + 1
'            groupList(groupCount) = records(num).group
'        End If
'    Next num
'Next GroupName
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
For Each GroupName In records
    For Each GroupName2 In groupList
        If records(counter).group = groupList(counter2) Then
            groupBool = True
        End If
        counter2 = counter2 + 1
    Next GroupName2
    If groupBool = False Then

Next GroupName

Cells(1, 1) = "Number of records: " & numOfRecords
Cells(1, 2) = "Number of Groups: " & groupCount
Cells(2, 1) = "records index: " & UBound(records) - LBound(records)
counter = 0
'For Each GroupName In groupList
'    Cells(3, counter) = GroupName
'    counter = counter + 1
'Next GroupName
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested simplified version of your code with a class instead of user defined type and it works just fine. One change was this `records.Add placeholder`. Parenthesis removed.

Answer (score 5):

Add a new class module, call it `Record`, move your `Type` in there, make it `Private`, and then declare a private field of that type, and expose a `Property Get` and a `Property Let` for each member:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TRecord
    Number As String
    Group As String
    Division As String
    Category As String
    Codes(1 To 5) As Long
End Type

Private this As TRecord

Public Property Get Number() As String
    Number = this.Number
End Property

Public Property Let Number(ByVal value As String)
    this.Number = value
End Property

Public Property Get Group() As String
    Group = this.Group
End Property

Public Property Let Group(ByVal value As String)
    this.Group = value
End Property

Public Property Get Division() As String
    Division = this.Division
End Property

Public Property Let Division(ByVal value As String)
    this.Division = value
End Property

Public Property Get Category() As String
    Category = this.Category
End Property

Public Property Let Category(ByVal value As String)
    this.Category = value
End Property

Public Property Get Code(ByVal index As Long) As Long
    Code = this.Codes(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Code(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As Long)
    this.Codes(index) = value
End Property
```

Now use instances of that class instead, and it should work fine.

For additional cool-factor, remove+export the class module, open it in Notepad, and set its `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute to `True`. Save, and re-import the module: now your class has a *default instance*, and with that you can have a *factory method*:

```
Public Function Create(ByVal pNumber As String, ByVal pGroup As String, ByVal pDivision As String, ByVal pCategory As String, ParamArray pCodes As Variant) As Record
    With New Record
        .Number = pNumber
        .Group = pGroup
        .Division = pDivision
        .Category = pCategory

        'todo assert number of parameters to prevent out-of-bounds error
        Dim i As Long
        For i = LBound(pCodes) To UBound(pCodes)
            .Code(i) = pCodes(i)
        Next

        Set Create = .Self
    End with
End Function

Public Property Get Self() As Record
    Set Self = Me
End Property
```

Now the reader loop can look like this:

```
Do Until EOF(1)
    numOfRecords = numOfRecords + 1
    Line Input #1, fileLine
    rowList = Split(fileLine, "|")
    records.Add Record.Create(rowList(0), rowList(1), rowList(2), rowList(3), rowList(4), rowList(5), rowList(6), rowList(7), rowList(8))
Loop
```

Note that a class' *default instance* **can** be abused to hold global state (e.g. like the way some people use `UserForm`'s default instances). That doesn't mean they *should*. Use default instances for "static" methods that belong to the *type* rather than an *instance*, and you'll do great.

Combined with interfaces, you could even simulate immutability, but I don't think you need to go there for this.

Comment: Thank you for this answer(+1) - if you can, please elaborate, or point to a good source on practice with "global state"/"static" default instances, and/or where the instances should be better put.

Comment: Essentially it's the exact same design principles that govern a `static class` in C# (`Shared Class` in VB.NET).

Comment: Thank you for the links, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use a class, name it cRecord

```
Option Explicit

Private Type RecordType
    number As String
    group As String
    div As String
    cat As String
    code1 As Integer
    code2 As Integer
    code3 As Integer
    code4 As Integer
    code5 As Integer
End Type

Dim mElement As RecordType

Property Let number(nval As String)
    mElement.number = nval
End Property

Property Let group(nval As String)
    mElement.group = nval
End Property

Property Let div(nval As String)
    mElement.div = nval
End Property

Property Let cat(nval As String)
    mElement.cat = nval
End Property
Property Let code1(nval As String)
    mElement.code1 = nval
End Property

Property Let code2(nval As String)
    mElement.code2 = nval
End Property

Property Let code3(nval As String)
    mElement.code3 = nval
End Property

Property Let code4(nval As String)
    mElement.code4 = nval
End Property

Property Let code5(nval As String)
    mElement.code5 = nval
End Property
```

and then change your code to

```
Dim placeholder As cRecord
Do Until EOF(1)
    numOfRecords = numOfRecords + 1
    Line Input #1, fileLine
    rowList = Split(fileLine, "|")
    Set placeholder = New cRecord
    placeholder.number = rowList(0)
    placeholder.group = rowList(1)
    placeholder.div = rowList(2)
    placeholder.cat = rowList(3)
    placeholder.code1 = rowList(4)
    placeholder.code2 = rowList(5)
    placeholder.code3 = rowList(6)
    placeholder.code4 = rowList(7)
    placeholder.code5 = rowList(8)

    records.Add placeholder
Loop`
```

Comment: I'll assume you had already started typing this answer up when I posted my answer 10 minutes ago - it otherwise doesn't bring anything new to the table. FWIW there is no need whatsoever to have that `c` prefix (or any prefix for that matter) on the class name. Also, write-only properties are a design smell.

Comment: Yes, I had already started it and saw afterwards that you were faster :-(  The other topic, of course, class needs to be "improved" by get properties and c-prefix is just sth I do (maybe a bad habit)  and is, of course, not neccessary.